# ObjectInputStream.readObject() NotSerializableException

Tags: java, android

I've got some problems saving and reading objects saved on a file with ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream in my Android app
I have two classes Workout and Exercise, Workout contains among other things a list of Exercise. Both classes implement Serializable. Here is the actual code:

**Workout**

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

public class Workout implements Serializable{

private String _name;
protected ArrayList<Exercise> _list = new ArrayList<Exercise>();
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
private File _fileSave;
final Context context = MyApp.getContext();

Workout(){
    _name = "Empty";
    _list = null;
 }

 Workout(String n, ArrayList<Exercise> e){
     _name = n;
     _list.addAll(e);
 }

 Workout(File fs){
     ObjectInputStream ois;
     _fileSave = fs;
     try{
         ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(fs));
         Workout n = (Workout) ois.readObject();   //here it fails and throws the exception
         ois.close();
         _name = n._name;
         _list = n._list;
     }catch(IOException e){ 
        e.getCause();
     }catch(ClassNotFoundException e) {
     }
 }

 protected void save(){                                 
    ObjectOutputStream oos;
    _fileSave = new File(context.getFilesDir(), _name + ".w");
    try{
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(_fileSave));
        oos.writeObject(this);
        oos.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.getCause();
    }
 }
 ...
```

**Exercise**

```
public class Exercise implements Serializable{

protected String _name;
protected int _weight;
protected int _reps;
protected int _sets;
protected int _pause;
protected int _duration;
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

Exercise(){
    _name = "New Empty Exercise";
    _weight = 0;
    _reps = 0;
    _sets = 0;
    _pause = 0;
}

Exercise(String n, int w, int r, int s, int d, int p){
    _name = n;
    _weight = w;
    _reps = r;
    _sets = s;
    _duration = d;
    _pause = p;
}
```

}

I have no problem saving current instance of the class but when I'm trying to read back the object a NotSerializableException is thrown. Here are the details and the backtrace:

```
cause = java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mycompany.myapp.MyApp

backtrace = { long[44]@b77201, class java.io.ObjectInputStream, class java.io.ObjectInputStream, class java.io.ObjectInputStream, class java.io.ObjectInputStream, class java.io.ObjectInputStream, class java.io.ObjectInputStream, class com.mycompany.myapp.Workout$0$debug, class com.mycompany.myapp.Workout, class com.mycompany.myapp.Menu$0$debug, class com.mycompany.myapp.Menu, class android.app.Activity, class android.app.Instrumentation, class android.app.ActivityThread, class android.app.ActivityThread, class android.app.ActivityThread, class android.app.ActivityThread$H, class android.os.Handler, class android.os.Looper, class android.app.ActivityThread, class java.lang.reflect.Method, class com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller, class com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit }
```

I can't understand what is my mistake or what I'm missing. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Context cannot be serialized. Make it transient. `transient final Context context = MyApp.getContext();`

Comment: You must also have got the same exception when serializing. Don't ignore exceptions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an object to be serializable, all of it's instance fields must be serializable, as well as all of their instance fields, and so on. Your `Workout` has,

```
final Context context = MyApp.getContext();
```

Android's `Context` object is not serializable. If your case, since you are apparently just storing the context in a static field, just remove the instance field for it and use `MyApp.getContent()` directly where you need it. Not that I condone using global variables.

Or, as pointed out by @Bedla in the comments,

```
transient final Context context = MyApp.getContext();
```

You can alternatively mark a field with `transient` to denote it should not be serialized. But of course, you have to be **prepared** for that field to not be deserialized.